# python does not exit program properly

Tags: python, recursion

In my program I want to interact with user and ask him to press specific letters to do some things (I think that logic of this game is not relevant for my question). When I start game and as first letter I press 'q' program exit immediately, but when I play for a while (use few times 'g' and 'r') I have to press few times 'q' too before I could exit program (Every time I'm getting the same prompt as on the beginnig of the game "Enter g to start ... ")
I'm using Canopy and Python 2.7.

```
t_h = '' 
def pg(wl):

    global t_h
    result = raw_input("Enter g to start new game, r to replay last game, or q to end game: ")
    possible_choices = ["g", "r", "q"]
    if result in possible_choices:
        if result == 'g':
            t_h = dh(n)
            ph(t_h, wl, n)
        if result == 'r':
            if t_h == '':
                print 'You have not played a game yet. Please play a new game first!'
            else:
                ph(t_h, wl, n)
        if result == 'q':
            return None
    else:
        print "Invalid letter." 
    return pg(wl)
```

Comment: You're calling your function recursively. Each recursion requires a `q` to get out of it. Replace the recursion with a loop.

Comment: ctrl+c always works :P

Comment: replace `return None`  with `exit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `pg` calls itself recursively on any non `possible_choice` case (since only `q` returns directly) -- that is, on the `return pg(wl)` line.

The situation you describe implies that either one of, or both `ph` and `dh` are calling `pg` again.
This means that for every non `q` input you will have a prompt for a new question on the stack from `ph` (or `ph` and `dh`) *and* one from the recursive call to `pg`. This will cause the exact behaviour you describe, where one `q` wont suffice to exit. With the code you posted -- that is, without `dh` and `ph` -- it is not possible to know precisely, but this is the logical conclusion.

If you want the possibility to exit immediately you would have to use a simple infinite loop with `break` in case of `q` instead of recursion.
Another possibility is following @PauloScardine's idea of using `exit()`, if what you want is really to exit the whole process. Again, with the piece of code you posted, it is not possible to know whether this is possible (`pg` being called directly from a `main` function).

Comment: you were right with your assumption that other function call pg too. I noticed that I have put return statement in ph for some case. It worked fine separately but caused strange behavior as I discribed above when I started to use pg. Now it works fine without that call inside pg. Thanks for your help and rest of ppl involed in this topic.

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell without seeing more of your code (specifically code for `dh` and `ph`), but I'd guess that `pg` is being called from one of those functions, or some other function in your code.

Comment: This is inaccurate: whatever `ph` does, a recursion already exists since at the end of the `if` block for the chosen letter, the `pg` gets called again, unless `q` was pressed. If `ph` calls `pg` the recursion is there from different sources, but this is the case even if `ph` doesn't.

Comment: From what I can tell, the recursive call is just acting as a goto. Try removing the non-recursive calls from hoodoo's code and run it. It will exit the first time you give it a `q`.

Comment: You are actually right, although I would not call that recursive call a goto. I adjusted my answer to reflect this point.